# MagicalRecord createEntity error in Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, magicalrecord

I have a crash in my Swift project with MagicalRecord - CoreData library : https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

First, I setup MagicalRecord OK in AppDelegate.swift:

```
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack() //-> This is OK. Don't crash
```

But, when I want to create a "Contact" entity instance I got a Crash.

My code is the next:

```
var context = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_contextForCurrentThread() // -> This is OK. Don't crash
var contact = Contact.MR_createInContext(context) // -> CRASH
```

All compile OK but when the App is running I get the next crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'MyProject.Contact' in this model.' *** First throw call stack: 
(0x27861f77 0x34870c77 0x27590c73 0x9b93d 0x74f28 0x75438 0x2aea6e33 0x2b09acef 0x2b09d19d 0x2b0a79f9 0x2b09ba5b 0x2e106141 0x2782881d 0x27827ae1 0x2782627f 0x27773da1 0x27773bb3 0x2aea0ae7 0x2ae9bc41 0x75ab0 0x75aec 0x34e10aaf) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

MyProject key is the $(PRODUCT_NAME), how I can fix this?

Kind regards

Comment: Please, don't use MR_contextForCurrentThread. You will crash, and it will be random and mysterious. Don't use it.

Answer (score 8):

There is a simple solution to this issue. Just add @objc(ClassName) before the swift NSManagedObject subclass. This allows the Objc side know the right name for the class. Otherwise it will include the module name which is bad in this case because it won't match what you have in your Core Data model. Here's and example from one of my swift projects...

@objc(Plant) public class Plant: NSManagedObject

Answer (score 4):

It seems like MagicalRecord automatically computes the entity name, and does this the wrong way. You can possibly fix this by adding the following code to your `Contact` class:

```
class func entityName() -> String {
    return "Contact"
}
```

Comment: I found that doing this solved my problem, however I needed to use the non shorthand version of the method `MR_entityName()`. This combined with adding the class prefix inside the Entity modeler worked.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, you likely need to set the class for your entity to `MyProject.Contact` for it to be found automatically though the model. In the Entity inspector on the right of the Entity modeler, you can change the class name there.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of Guido Hendriks with an extension to support all managed objects:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. I Think that Guido Hendriks's is a good answer. I tried casademora answer but I didn't got the App work.
Finally I have changed the CoreData classes language (Contact Class) from Swift to Objective-C and now the MagicalRecord library works fine!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with the same problem and took me a while to figure out how to...
Thanks @casademora I created the classes as Obj-C ones and imported the headers in bridging-header of my swift project.

1. Select your .xcdatamodeld file
2. Editor
3. Create NSManagedObject Subclass
4. Select your data model and entities
5. Save the file as an Objective-C class

Here you go with a nice picture:

[image]

And in the prefix header file:

```
#ifndef DBSwiftTest_Bridging_Header_h
#define DBSwiftTest_Bridging_Header_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 

#import "DKDBManager.h" // My database manager
#import "Runner.h"      // My model in this example

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your entity classes in objective-c and exposing them via bridging header to swift. That way crash dissappears

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Here is what i did to solve it:

Step 1: As Guido Hendriks mentioned in his answer

> It seems like MagicalRecord automatically computes the entity name, and does this the wrong way. You can possibly fix this by adding the following code to your Contact class"

```
class func entityName() -> String {
    return "Contact"
}
```

Step 2: In your DataModel, change the Class of the Entity from Contact to ProjectName.Contact

[image]